# android camera+activity split screen

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a split screen that would have a camera preview and a second activity in the same screen? Would fragments do the job? (I am new to android and never worked with fragments). I am converting the screen colors from RGB into HSV (using OpenCV) and would like to manipulate values of H, S and V using seek bars. At the moment I am doing this in the following way:

1)press button to go to a new activity and set the values using seek bars 
2)press button to go back to camera preview and get the HSV values using intents

But this involves a lot of switching between activities and checking whether I achieved the desired effect and I would like to achieve a real time preview so when changing the values I immediately see the changes. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Camera preview simply writes on a `SurfaceView`.  You can put the preview anywhere you want and any size you want just like any other View object.  I do think a current limitation is you can't move the preview once it's set without first disabling the camera (though not 100% sure).

As such, you can put the `SurfaceView` and your other `View` in a `LinearLayout`.  Give them both the same weight, and both views will take up half the screen (assuming they're the only two in the layout).